# Find the maximum sum of a specific number of values in a vector - Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a vector with 8760 values (the values could be like 1.2, 3.0, 7.6, 2.5, 8.4, 6.3  etc) and I want to find these **24 consecutive** values that give the **maximum sum**. I would also like to know **the specific position** of the first value are this sum.

The vector is an Excel file that is read in Matlab as `Pload=xlsread('demand.xlsx');`

Comment: first add what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you insist on Matlab, you can use the `conv` (convolution) function to do the sum for you, then find the position of the max:

Assuming your data are in a vector named `A`, and I call `nc` the number of consecutive data for the summation:

```
nc = 24 ;             %// number of consecutive values to sum
kn = ones(nc,1) ;     %// define a kernel for the convolution

C = conv(A,kn) ;      %// calculate a "moving sum"
[~,idx] = max(C) ;    %// find the max of the convolution result
idx = idx - nc + 1 ;  %// The starting index of the FIRST maximum sum is here
```

If you have several identical maximum, this will only return the index of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Put the values in column **A**.  In **B24** enter:

```
=SUM(A1:A24)
```

Copy this downwards.

Finally use:

```
=MAX(B24:B7860)
```

To get the position, use **=MATCH()**